# How to replace "\" with "/" in python?

Tags: python, string, path

I have a value `path = V:\PRODUCTIONS\SC_02\SHOT_310\compRender\main\v003\2560x1440_exr\SC_02_SHOT_310_Compositing_main_v003.1001.exr` and I need to replace backslash with common slash.

Using `.replace("\\",'/')` or `normpath` gives me: `V:/PRODUCTIONS/SC_02/SHOT_310/compRender/main003�0x1440_exr/SC_02_SHOT_310_Compositing_main_v003.1001.exr`

I figuered out that I could replace "\v" with "/v" and get away with that, but "\256" gives me special character, and I can't search for "\256" since that value in string is changing depending on files.

Also I am unable to use "r" in front of string, like `path=r"V:\PRODUCTIONS\SC_02\SHOT_310\compRender\main\v003\2560x1440_exr\SC_02_SHOT_310_Compositing_main_v003.1001.exr"` since I'm not creating path values, it is forwarded to me.

Comment: Looks like you're having a string literal because `\256` becomes `�`

Comment: Where is the path variable coming from? It looks like the backslashes aren't being escaped.

Comment: Try using a raw string: `r"..."`. It will treat backslashes literally.

Comment: have you looked into REGEX (regular expressions) format?

Comment: The question would be a lot less confusing if you'd be consistent with the strings you use for an example. Show us one that actually demonstrates the problem!

Comment: @Skyler 'path' variable is forwarded from another function, to which I don't have an access.
@a_guest Problem is that I am receiving variable `path` from another function and using `rpath` would report an error.

@MarkRansom There is only one string in my example?

Comment: OP, does your output always follow this format? Will the resolution always remain the same?

Comment: @Coldspeed Format is always the same, but resolution is changing, therefore I can't just replace `\256` with `/256`.

Comment: Okay, but will there be a fixed set of resolutions that path can have? Because if there are, I might have a solution...

Comment: @Coldspeed Hypothetically, I could make a list of all resolutions which could be used. Are you suggesting to compare resolution of the path with all resolutions in the list until I find the right one and than replace it together with backslash, something like replace `\resolution` with `/resolution`?

Comment: Not with a forward slash, but you've got the idea.

Comment: @Coldspeed Yeah, that should work, if I don't find neater solution I might just go with that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, there's a bit more I want to say. I'll write an answer. You're not obligated to accept.

Comment: Your string is messed up at the source. If you can't fix it at your end, you'll need to go back to whoever's sending you that string and tell them to fix their broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're receiving a variable from another unmodifiable source, the string has already been escaped.

Now, with your string, there are two places where characters are misinterpreted: `\v` and `\256`.

```
>>> path = 'V:\PRODUCTIONS\SC_02\SHOT_310\compRender\main\v003\2560x1440_exr\SC_02_SHOT_310_Compositing_main_v003.1001.exr'
>>> path
'V:\\PRODUCTIONS\\SC_02\\SHOT_310\\compRender\\main\x0b003®0x1440_exr\\SC_02_SHOT_310_Compositing_main_v003.1001.exr'
# ----------------------------------------------^-----^
```

The good thing is, raw strings are part of the syntax, not part of the string. The issue is in the way python interprets your strings. One thing you can do is look for these problematic symbols and replace them. Here's a modified version of this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211/) that handles most use cases:

```
def raw(text):
    escape_dict={'\a':r'\a',
        '\b':r'\b',
        '\c':r'\c',
        '\f':r'\f',
        '\n':r'\n',
        '\r':r'\r',
        '\t':r'\t',
        '\v':r'\v',
        '\'':r'\'',
        '\"':r'\"',
        '\0':r'\0',
        '\1':r'\1',
        '\2':r'\2',
        '\3':r'\3',
        '\4':r'\4',
        '\5':r'\5',
        '\6':r'\6',
        '\7':r'\7',
        '\8':r'\8',
        '\9':r'\9',
         '\256': r'\256'} # notice this line is the first 3 digits of the resolution

    for k in escape_dict:
        if text.find(k) > -1:
            text = text.replace(k, escape_dict[k])

    return text
```

This function will replace any misinterpreted special symbols with their raw equivalent.

If you call this defined earlier, you get:

```
>>> raw(path)   
 'V:\\PRODUCTIONS\\SC_02\\SHOT_310\\compRender\\main\\v003\\2560x1440_exr\\SC_02_SHOT_310_Compositing_main_v003.1001.exr'
```

You'll have to manually add more resolution values as required.

Comment: I guess I'll go with this one, this is best solution so far. Thanks!